# Google Organization Account Signin for IOS

Tags: ios, openid, google-plus

Our organization is trying to build a internal tool for management and we already had a web portal for this with authentication using our organization's gmail account.(say aaa@xx.com, xx is the organization name), which is implemented by OpenID.

I am trying to do the iOS version for the internal tool. However when implementing google authentication, I encountered some problem:

I looked for OpenID for iOS but I found not available source. Then I found google plus has an iOS SDK for authentication however google plus is not available for organization account.

I want to know what is the best approach to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opt to embed a web view and login to google in the web view, our backend actually checks cookie when handling requests, and after login in web view, the cookie is automatically set by iOS.